# Getting OutOfMemoryError GC overhead limit exceeded when collecting a dataset in Java Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have some data of approximate size 250MB.

I want to load the data and convert it to a map

```
class MyData implements Serializable {

    private Map<String, List<SomeObject>> myMap;

    MyData(SparkSession sparkSession, String inputPath) {

        Dataset<Klass> ds = sparkSession.read().json(inputPath).as(Encoders.bean(Klass.class));
        myMap = ds.collectAsList().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                    Klass::getField1(),
                                    Klass::getField2()
                            )
                    );
    }
}
```

This is my spark execution configuration

```
--master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --executor-cores 2 --num-executors 200 --executor-memory 10240M
```

Is it not a good practice to convert dataset to a list/map ? Or is it a configuration issue ? Or a code issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your collecting all the data in the Dataset into the Spark driver with:

```
myMap = ds.collectAsList()...
```

Therefore you should set the driver memory with `--driver-memory 2G` on the command line (aka your "spark execution configuration".

The default value for this parameter is `1G` which is likely not quite enough for 250M of raw data.